# ng-repeat showing empty table rows

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I getting empty `<td>` tags when I am using `ng-repeat`. The number of `<td>`s is equal to the number of records returned from the service/api. I have checked in **ng-inspector** `scope` has proper records. Can anybody point where I am doing it wrong?

Index.html looks like:-

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Admin</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/ngDatepicker/src/css/ngDatepicker.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style-responsive.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="ojadminuiApp">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
   <section id="container" >
      <!-- **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
      TOP BAR CONTENT & NOTIFICATIONS
      *********************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->
      <!--header start-->
      <header class="header black-bg">
              <div class="sidebar-toggle-box">
                  <div class="fa fa-bars tooltips" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Toggle Navigation"></div>
              </div>
            <!--logo start-->
            <a href="index.html" class="logo"><b>Online Judgments - Admin Panel</b></a>
            <!--logo end-->

            </div>
            <div class="top-menu">
              <ul class="nav pull-right top-menu">
                    <li><a class="logout" href="login.html">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
      <!--header end-->

      <!-- **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
      MAIN SIDEBAR MENU
      *********************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->
      <!--sidebar start-->
      <aside>
          <div id="sidebar"  class="nav-collapse ">
              <!-- sidebar menu start-->
              <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">

                  <p class="centered"><img src="images/logo.jpg" class="img-circle" width="60"></p>
                  <h5 class="centered">Admin Menu</h5>                    
                  <li>
                      <a ng-href="#/AddSubscriber">
                          <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
                          <span>Add Subscriber</span>
                      </a>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                      <a ng-href="#/">
                          <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                          <span>Manage Subscribers</span>
                      </a>
                  </li>                  
              </ul>
              <!-- sidebar menu end-->
          </div>
      </aside>
      <!--sidebar end-->

      <!-- **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
      MAIN CONTENT
      *********************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->
      <!--main content start-->
      <div ng-view="">
      </div>

      <!-- /MAIN CONTENT -->

      <!--main content end-->
      <!--footer start-->
      <footer class="site-footer">
          <div class="text-center">
              Test admin
              <a href="#" class="go-top">
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
              </a>
          </div>
      </footer>
      <!--footer end-->
  </section>


    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery.nicescroll/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/dcjqaccordion/js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ngDatepicker/src/js/ngDatepicker.min.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/common-scripts.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/addsubscriber.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/journalsservice.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/courtsservice.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/managesubscriber.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/userservice.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/directives/datepickerpopup.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/formatdate.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

View looks like:

```
<section id="main-content">
    <section class="wrapper">

        <h3><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Manage Subscriber</h3>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Search</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text to Search">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12"> 

            <div class="content-panel">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">
                    <thead class="cf">
                        <tr>
                            <th>User Name</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Password</th>
                            <th>Start Date</th>
                            <th>End Date</th>
                            <th>Mobile</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="user in Users | filter:search">
                            <td data-title="User Name"><a href="#/ViewSubscriber/{{user.UserId}}" >{{user.UserName}}</a></td>
                            <td data-title="Name">{{user.FirstName + ' ' + user.LastName }}</td>
                            <td data-title="Password">{{user.Password}}</td>
                            <td data-title="Start Date">{{user.StartDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                            <td data-title="End Date">{{user.EndDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                            <td data-title="Mobile">{{user.Mobile}}</td>
                            <td data-title="Address">
                                {{ user.Address1 + ' ' + 
                                user.Address2 + ' ' + 
                                user.Address3 + ' ' + 
                                user.State +  ' ' + 
                                user.PinCode + ' ' + 
                                user.Country }}
                            </td>
                            <td data-title="Phone">{{user.StdCode + ' ' + user.Phone}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#/AddSubscriber/{{user.UserId}}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>           
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>
```

app.js looks like:

```
angular
  .module('ojadminuiApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'toastr',
    'jkuri.datepicker'
  ])
  .constant('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/OnlineAdmin.API/api/')
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/manageSubscriber.html',
        controller: 'ManagesubscriberCtrl'
      })
      .when('/AddSubscriber', {
        templateUrl: 'views/addSubscriber.html',
        controller: 'AddsubscriberCtrl'
      })
      .when('/AddSubscriber/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'views/addSubscriber.html',
        controller: 'AddsubscriberCtrl'
      })
      .when('/ViewSubscriber/:id',{
        templateUrl : 'views/viewSubscriber.html',
        controller: 'AddsubscriberCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

controller looks like:

```
angular.module('ojadminuiApp')
  .controller('ManagesubscriberCtrl', function ($scope, userService) {
    $scope.Users = userService.query();
  });
```

Output from service/api looks like

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1033,
    "userName": "test@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "testfirst",
    "password": "testpass1",
    "lastName": "tstlast",
    "startDate": "2016-08-02T00:00:00",
    "endDate": "2018-02-24T00:00:00",
    "createdDate": "2016-02-08T19:18:24.357",
    "updatedDate": "2016-02-08T19:45:11.373",
    "mobile": "939393993",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "address1": "Ad1",
    "address2": "AD2",
    "address3": "AD3",
    "country": "tstctry",
    "state": "tststate",
    "pincode": "100011",
    "stdCode": "080",
    "phone": "309333030"
  }
]
```

My factory looks like:-

```
angular.module('ojadminuiApp')
  .factory('userService', function ($resource, BASE_URL) {
      return $resource(BASE_URL +'users/:id', null,
    {
        'update': { method:'PUT' , params: {id: '@id'}}
    });
  });
```

Comment: Problem description is not clear. Are you saying rows are created but cells are empty? Also please remove irrelevant code like sidebar, router etc that aren't part of the problem

Comment: yes there is no data inside cells

Comment: So what does a row object look like in json? Seems you aren't targeting properties correctly within `{{}}`

Comment: Or is there a directive doing anything with `data-title`?

Comment: Please provide `data-title` description or its code and If possible provide json response returned by your api call.

Comment: Added the output json

Comment: data-title is just a normal html attribute. Not used data-title in code.

Comment: @Saroj basically you were missed data assignment part..do look at mine answer below

Comment: @Pankaj ng-repeat is generating same no. of empty table rows that are coming from the service. Both your code and my code giving same result i.e. empty table rows.

Comment: javascript is case sensitive. You aren't assigning correct properties in view

Comment: Your object binding has a problem..look at my updated answer

Comment: oh somebody changed API. Actually it was working fine. Somebody Added 
var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
Which made JSON properties to camel case.
Thanks Pankaj for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a typo while binding value to view.

You should follow cammel case instead of title case like

```
{{user.firstName}}
```

To resolve above binding field issue for all fields, as accessing object with key is case sensitive.

Comment: I tried your code its not working. When i am using my code my scope is properly getting populated(verified using nginspector).

Comment: Can you put {{Users}} on view, to verify what has assigned to scope variable

Comment: When i used {{Users}}  i am getting proper json response that is coming from API

Comment: actually `$resource` methods return array or object which is why you can directly assign to scope. It's empty at beginning ...then gets populated internally

Comment: @chartlietfl correct..here it will work..but in most of the cases we should use $promise.then to ensure/do stuff(like hide loading) before data assignment happen..

Comment: agree... I never use `$resource` , don't like it

Comment: Exactly..that will not give us visibility what has happened with AP endI..its failed or succeed..

Answer (score 0):

Oh somebody changed API. Actually it was working fine. Somebody added following lines. I removed following lines and it started working again.

```
var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Above lines of code made all JSON properties to camel case. Thanks Pankaj for pointing that out.